# Excel Countifs - include and exclude

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, countif

In Excel 2013: Im trying to count the names in column A (not including TBA)
=COUNTIF A2:A40, "

=COUNTIF A2:A40, "2017")

Comment: If you're curious about the downvotes, I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  This is a relatively straightforward use of `Countifs()`...

Comment: OK, so you cant help, Thanks anyway

Comment: In Excel 2013: Im trying to count the names in column A (not including TBA)
=COUNTIF A2:A40, "<TBA")plus the number of Fitters in column B =COUNTIF A2:A40, "<TBA", B2:B40,"=Fitter", plus year in column E, (only if greater than 2017) however I keep getting an error message??  Please help

=COUNTIF A2:A40, "<TBA", B2:B40,"=Fitter", E2:E40, ">2017")

Comment: @KYlee Put your sample data in the post and show output manually then explain logic to gain the output. We will try to do that by formula.

Comment: @KYlee you'd be well advised to drop the snottiness. Bruce Wayne posted a valid suggestion. You will need to apply your reading skills, though. I'll write this slowly, so you can take it in: Countif() takes one comparison. Countifs() takes many. Explore Countifs().

Comment: You don't mention using a filter in your OP, but you do in a comment. Is it literally "=Filter", or is that an example? Also, and I'm asking sincerely, are you just forgetting the `(` or is the left parenthesis broken on your keyboard? Finally, I/we can help, however, we ask that you include what you've tried, post sample data, etc. which is outlined in the "How to Ask" page I linked to earlier.  Finally, to reiterate @teylyn, have you tried `Countifs()`?

Answer (score 0):

This works for the first  part about TBA :

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A40, "<>TBA")
```

Note it will count anything except tba...